# read file from weburl java

Tags: file, fileinputstream

I am trying to read file from web url

### method 1

```
    try {
        String fileUrl = "https://github.com/DhyanandraSingh/appointment-mt/StudentInternship.xlsx";
        URL url = new URI(fileUrl).toURL();
        FileInputStream excelFile = new FileInputStream(new File(url.toString()));
}catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

but it throw error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: https:\github.com\DhyanandraSingh\appointment-mt\StudentInternship.xlsx (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
```

but when i read any local file it will work.

### method 2

i also tried but result is same `fileNotFoundException`

```
URLConnection connection = new URL(fileUrl).openConnection();
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);
InputStream response = connection.getInputStream();
```

Comment: You cannot read a file from a remote server through https using a java.io.File. Read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/using-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests/2793153#2793153 to perform an HTTP get to get the file.